# How to apply (or maintain) line style in Raphael after scaling?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

In [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) (a JavaScript library for working with SVG), [you can apply transformations to an element](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform), such as rotation, translation, and scaling.

So let's say I want to make a line that is 8 pixels wide. I can do something like this:

```
paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 200, 200);
paper.path("M 0,0 l 200,200").attr({"stroke-width": "8px"});
```

But if I want to scale that line somehow, I lose my 8 pixel width and it falls back to the standard 1 pixel width.

```
paper.path("M 0,0 l 200,200").attr({"stroke-width": "8px"}).transform("s -1,1");
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to make any scaled line that maintains its stroke width. Other transformations work fine. It seems to be just scaling that has this issue. And I experience the same problem in both Firefox and Chrome.

[Here is an example of my problem on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fUcvD/3/) As you can see, rotation and translation work fine, but scaling doesn't.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow applying the transform changes the stroke-width to NaN. Perhaps it's a bug. You can apply the transform using a [matrix transform](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/fUcvD/4/) though.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I looked through the Raphael code and couldn't figure out what is causing this bug, but I did figure out that if you input the stroke-width as an integer like 8 rather than as a string like "8px", the bug goes away. That's probably an easier fix if anyone else has this problem.